# Generating 4-Digit Passwords, But Skipping Bad Words

Tags: database, text-files

We have an application that will be generating 4-digit random strings for guest WiFi usage. So you walk into a hotel, get your room key and your WiFi password. I want to make these generated passwords as simple as possible to save calls to the helpdesk, but not so simple that they are so easily guessed.

The problem is that inevitably you'll end up with passwords like "`POOP`" or "`DICK`". I think a simple solution is so to have a database table of the "forbidden" words, and upon generation check it against the database first to make sure it isn't a banned word.

I have looked at probably dozens of filtered/banned/censored word lists, but I can't find one that is sufficiently detailed so as to include things like `DIKK` and `P00P`, and I don't exactly want to use my time today to try to think of every possible offensive 4-letter combination and type them all out manually.

Does anyone have a good resource/word list that would contain these "potentially-offensive" strings?

Comment: Consider generating random strings without vowels. You won't get any actual english words. You will both avoid words like 'tree' or 'fukc'

Comment: That is a fantastic idea! I'll run a few thousand iterations through the function and read through the list. Worst case, it will make the list of banned words much shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First I wrote this as a comment. But then I realized it actually answers your question about skipping offensive words:*

Consider generating random strings without vowels. You won't get any actual english word. You will both avoid words like 'tree' or 'fukc'

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use numbers too, will be "more secure" and you will eliminate this problem

Comment: Numbers are part of the generation methodology. Adding numbers will not, however, eliminate the problem in the slightest, and will actually exacerbate the problem by adding more potential potentially-offensive words to the list (like `D1CK`)

Comment: 1,679,616 combinations, you will never have d1ck, po0p ... etc